# Create magazine app using xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, newsstand-kit

I want to create a Magazine app for the Newsstand in Xcode 4.2.

Are there any good tutorials on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/

This explains everything about Newsstand applications. Go through it. You will understand clearly and also check apple documentation.

http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/29/at-newsstand-and-subscriptions/

This is the second part of the tutorial.